# Добавление словаря в словаре python

Tags: python, словари

Пока для теста я пишу бота, которому я буду отправлять список сайтов, а он будет опрашивать их каждый сколько-то минут. (я знаю что таких полно, и у меня даже на зеннопостере это работает, но пишу для тренировки). И вот чтобы бот мог работать и для других людей, я сохраняю то, что они вводят в словарь в соответствии с айдишником чата с пользователем. И тут закралась проблема

Есть словарь:

URLIST = {client1:{site1:code1}, client2{site2:code2},{site3,code3 }}

И мне нужно добавлять новых клиентов и для каждого по несколько сайтов и кодов к ним.
И вот тут кроется проблема.
Если у меня появляется клиент3 то я пишу

URLLIST[client3] = {site4:code4}
и тут все ок
Но если мне нужно добавить к клиенту 3 еще сайт с кодом, то

URLLIST[client3] = {site5:code5}

то прошлый сайт и код у этого клиента удаляется...
Если применять конструкцию

URLLIST[client3][site4] = code4 - то она срабатывает только в том случае, если client3 уже имел записи... если нет - то не работает

Я хотел было через if проверять существуют ли записи для клиента 3, но выяснилось - если его еще не было -то проверка выдает ошибку и программа вылетает.

---

Вопрос :

Как к списку URLIST = {client1:{site1:code1}, client2{site2:code2},{site3,code3 }}
Добавить сначала клиента 3 сайтом и кодом
И затем добавить к клиенту 3 еще сколько угодно сайтов и кодов ?

сам код если что в оригинале (в нем я пытался обойти проблему с помощью проверки наличия пользователя в словаре) :

```
    import telebot
from collections import defaultdict

START, ADDURL, ADDURLCODE, CHECKENTER, DELURL = range(5)
ENTEREDURL, ENTEREDCODE = range(2)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxsa55SVw-5xxxxxxx')
URLLIST = {}
ENTEREDURL = defaultdict()
ENTEREDCODE = defaultdict()
USER_STATE = defaultdict(lambda: START)

def update_urllist (message):    #записать урл в словарь пользователя
    if len(URLLIST[message.chat.id])<1:
        URLLIST[message.chat.id] = {ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id]:ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id]}
    else:
        URLLIST[message.chat.id][ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id]] = ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id]

def entersiteurl (message):        #записать какой урл текущий юзер
    ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id] = message.text

def entersitecode (message):        #записать какой код текущий юзер
    ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id] = message.text

def get_state (message):        #получить статус
    return USER_STATE[message.chat.id]

def update_state (message, state):    #записать статус
    USER_STATE[message.chat.id] = state
#-----------------------------------------

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет я умею следить за работоспособность сайтов, опрашивая их URL каждые 5 минут")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Доступны команды /add /del /list")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['list'])
def addurl(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш текущий список сайтов на проверке:")
    sitelist = list(URLLIST[message.chat.id].keys())
    print (sitelist)
    print(URLLIST[message.chat.id].items())
    print(URLLIST[message.chat.id])
    for site in sitelist:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(site))
#    bot.send_message(str(URLLIST[message.chat.id]))
#    print (str(URLLIST[message.chat.id]))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def addurl(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "пришли URL для добавления в список")
    update_state(message, ADDURL)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: get_state(message) == ADDURL)
def addurl(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пришли любой уникальный код для проверки для сайта")
    update_state(message, ADDURLCODE)
    entersiteurl(message)  # записать какой урл текущий юзер


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: get_state(message) == ADDURLCODE)
def addurl(message):
    entersitecode(message)  # записать какой код урла ввел текущий юзер
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добавляем "+str(ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id])+"с кодом проверки "+str(ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id]))
    update_state(message, CHECKENTER)
    update_urllist(message)
    update_state(message, START)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: `URLIST = {client1:{site1:code1}, client2{site2:code2},{site3,code3 }, client3: {}}`

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже сами описали решение в вопросе: "Я хотел было через if проверять существуют ли записи для клиента 3". Ниже рабочий код. Если у вас возникает ошибка, то пришлите код ошибки, тогда можно понять с чем нужно разобраться.

```
from collections import defaultdict as df

URLIST = df()

def add_clients_urls(client, site, code):
    if client in URLIST:
        URLIST[client][site] = code
    else:
        URLIST[client] = {site: code}
    print(URLIST)


add_clients_urls('client1', 'site1', 'code1')
add_clients_urls('client1', 'site2', 'code2')
add_clients_urls('client2', 'site3', 'code3')
add_clients_urls('client3', 'site1', 'code1')
add_clients_urls('client3', 'site4', 'code4')
```

Результат:
defaultdict(None, {'client1': {'site1': 'code1'}})
defaultdict(None, {'client1': {'site1': 'code1', 'site2': 'code2'}})
defaultdict(None, {'client1': {'site1': 'code1', 'site2': 'code2'}, 'client2': {'site3': 'code3'}})
defaultdict(None, {'client1': {'site1': 'code1', 'site2': 'code2'}, 'client2': {'site3': 'code3'}, 'client3': {'site1': 'code1'}})
defaultdict(None, {'client1': {'site1': 'code1', 'site2': 'code2'}, 'client2': {'site3': 'code3'}, 'client3': {'site1': 'code1', 'site4': 'code4'}})

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ, самое смешное, что в итоге я додумался до него сам и написал один в один тотже код, что у вас : Вообщем в итоге я додумался до простого решения - проверить - встречается ли userid в листе - если нет, то это новый пользователь и записи к нему в словарь добавляем одним способом, если не новый - то вторым

if message.chat.id in URLLIST:
    URLLIST[message.chat.id][ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id]] = ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id]
else:
    URLLIST[message.chat.id] = {ENTEREDURL[message.chat.id]: ENTEREDCODE[message.chat.id]}